# Compare 2 vectors and add missing values from target vector in R

Tags: r

I am using R and I have a `correct` vector whose `names` contain all the target names (`names(correct) <- c("A","B","C","D","E")`) such as:

```
correct <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
names(correct) <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
```

The vector I have to modify, instead, `tofix`, has names that may miss some values compared to `correct` above, in the example below is missing "C" and "E".

```
tofix <- c(2,5,4)
names(tofix) <- c("A","B","D")
```

So I want to fix it in a way that the resulting vector, `fixed`, contains the same names as in `correct` and with the same order, and when the name is missing adds 0 as a value, like the below:

```
fixed <- c(2,5,0,4,0)
names(fixed) <- names(correct)
```

Any idea how to do this in R? I tried with multiple if statements and for loops, but time complexity was far from ideal.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
fixed <- rep(0, length(correct))
fixed[match(names(tofix), names(correct))] <- tofix
names(fixed) <- names(correct)
fixed

A B C D E 
2 5 0 4 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unlist(modifyList(as.list(table(names(correct))*0), as.list(tofix)))
A B C D E 
2 5 0 4 0
```